# Is there a more recent official presentation (than Aug 11) on the Israel's Covid-19 vaccine effectiveness, particularly on the booster shot?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, reference-request

If found two-three previous ones ([July](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/vaccine-efficacy-safety-follow-up-committee/he/files_publications_corona_two-dose-vaccination-data.pdf), [2nd/longer variant](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/vaccine-efficacy-safety-follow-up-committee/he/files_publications_corona_ve-data-25072021.pdf), [August 11](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/vpb-12082021/he/files_publications_corona_vpb-12082021-01.pdf)), but Reuters [claims on Aug 22](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/israel-finds-covid-19-vaccine-booster-significantly-lowers-infection-risk-2021-08-22/) there's one about the booster effectiveness, and it's almost certainly not one of those three I found.

So, can anyone locate the one that Reuters claims to exist, about booster effectiveness?

> A third dose of Pfizer's COVID-19 vaccine has significantly improved protection from infection and serious illness among people age 60 and older in Israel compared with those who received two shots, findings published on Sunday by the Health Ministry showed.
>
> The data were presented at a meeting of a ministry panel of vaccination experts on Thursday and uploaded to its website on Sunday, though the full details of the study were not released.

"Sunday" would be Aug 22 and "Thursday" Aug 19.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't found that one, but it's probably covering the same data as the [preprint](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.08.27.21262679v1) that [impressed](https://www.medpagetoday.com/infectiousdisease/covid19vaccine/94344) Fauci.

> Twelve days or more after the booster dose we found an 11.4-fold (95% CI: [10.0, 12.9]) decrease in the relative risk of confirmed infection, and a >10-fold decrease in the relative risk of severe illness. Under a conservative sensitivity analysis, we find ≈5-fold protection against confirmed infection.
>
> [image]

Comment: That study was published in NEJM today https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2114255